# jquery multiple scrollpane in one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jscrollpane

is it possible to have multiple jquery scrollpane on one page? currently I have, but I guess that because the same class `".scroll-pane"` when i drag one slider, all are moving.

any ideas on this? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible and simple to use multiple scrollpane on the same page.

**Html**

```
<div class="scroll-pane">
 <p>your content here</p>
 <p>your content here</p>
 <p>your content here</p>
 <p>your content here</p>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.scroll-pane {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.horizontal-only {
 height: auto;
 max-height: 200px;
}​
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();​
```

Check demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/e88D5/1/)

If you have another issue, it would be great to provide the link.